# Automatically lengthen y-axis to include highest bar ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, automation, yaxis

I am looking for a piece of code that automatically sets the upper value of the y-axis one unit higher than my highest bar. Ofcourse, I can do this manually for each single bar graph I plot with the ylim function, but I am looking for a more elegant way in which R configures the upper y value one tick higher than the previous tick.

```
lf <- mtcars
lf$cyl <- as.factor(lf$cyl)
lf$am <- as.factor(lf$am)
lf$am <- revalue(lf$am, c("0"="Automatic", "1"="Manual"))

#You can see that the last y-axis tick is less than the higher bar
lf1 <- aggregate(mpg ~ am + cyl, lf, mean)                                
ggplot(lf1, aes(x = am, fill = cyl , y = mpg)) 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7) +
  theme_bw()

#This solves it, but I have to adjust ylim manually (and I don't want that ;))
lf1 <- aggregate(mpg ~ am + cyl, lf, mean)                                
ggplot(lf1, aes(x = am, fill = cyl , y = mpg)) 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7) +
  ylim(0, 30) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that long ago, ggplot2 added the ability to supply limits with a function whose input is the automatically calculated limits (similar to calling `range(your_data)`). To get the y-axis one unit longer than the highest bar, you could do the following:

```
ggplot(lf1, aes(x = am, fill = cyl , y = mpg)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = function(x){x + c(0,1)}) +
  theme_bw()
```

Keep in mind though, that by default the axis is still expanded, so if you want to get those exact limits, you would have to do the following:

```
ggplot(lf1, aes(x = am, fill = cyl , y = mpg)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), width = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = function(x){x + c(0,1)},
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Ha teunbrand, thank you. Unfortunately, with exact the same code as you are using, I get an error: Error in rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(self$limits) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

Comment: What is your ggplot2 version? I used 3.2.0

Comment: That could be it! I am at the moment not in the position to test, but I will get back on this.